# Как решить задачу о перекрытии отрезков за O(n*log(n)) c помощью stream api java, если есть решение старыми средствами?

Tags: java, алгоритм, java-8, java-stream

Есть класс:

```
public class Segment {
    int start;
    int finish;

public Segment(int start, int finish) {
    this.start = start;
    this.finish = finish;
}
}
```

В этом классе переопределен **equals** и **hashcode**. Сегмент задаёт закрытый интервал, к примеру **[5;5]** - одна точка, **[5; 8]** - четыре точки *5, 6, 7, 8*.

Нужно написать метод (лямбдами), такой, который принимает два массива этих сегментов. На выходе метод должен дать слитый массив сегментов, причем отрезки из второго массива попадут туда наверняка, а из первого - только те, которые не перекрылись вторым массивом. Вторые отрезки перекрывают первые. Простой пример - в первом массиве один сегмент **[0; 10]**, во втором - один сегмент **[5; 6]**. На выходе - массив с тремя элементами - **[0;4]**, **[5; 6]**, **[7; 10]**;
Так как звучит непонятно, я нарисовал, что должен делать метод.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод я тоже написал. Работает за O(nlog(n)) - предположительно. Суть его в том, что:

1. Два входных массива копируются.
2. Массивы сначала сортируются по началу. O(nlog(n))
3. Далее есть два цикла - внешний (обходит первый массив) и внутренний - обходит внутренний. В этих циклах отрезки сравниваются и отрезки с первого массива режутся, не включаются и иногда включаются целиком.
4. Как только конец одного из отрезков начинает лежать раньше начала второго (и наоборот), этот отрезок удаляется из массива, чтобы не тратить лишние ресурсы на сравнение его с другими отрезками.

В общем - метод получился длинным.

```
  static ArrayList<Segment> overlap(ArrayList <Segment> one_in, ArrayList <Segment> two_in){
       ArrayList <Segment> one = new ArrayList<>(one_in);
       ArrayList <Segment> two = new ArrayList<>(two_in);
        one.sort(base);
        two.sort(base);
      ArrayList <Segment> result = new ArrayList<>();

      ListIterator <Segment> one_iter = one.listIterator();
      ListIterator <Segment> two_iter = two.listIterator();
      Segment s = null;
      Segment t = null;
      OUTER:
      for(;one_iter.hasNext();)
      {
           s = one_iter.next();
          two_iter=two.listIterator();
         for(;two_iter.hasNext();){
           t = two_iter.next();
             if(t.start>s.finish) {
               result.add(s);
               one.remove(s);
               one_iter=one.listIterator();
               continue OUTER;
             }
             if(t.finish<s.start){
                 two.remove(t);
                 result.add(t);
                 two_iter = two.listIterator();
                 continue;
             }

             if(s.start<t.start){
               result.add(new Segment(s.start, t.start-1));
               if(t.finish>=s.finish){
                 //  two.remove(t); //ew
                 //  result.add(t);
                   two_iter = two.listIterator();
                   one.remove(s); //ew
                   one_iter=one.listIterator(); //ew
                   continue OUTER;
               }
               if(t.finish<s.finish){
                   result.add(t);
                   two.remove(t);
                   two_iter = two.listIterator();
                   s.start = t.finish+1;
                   continue;
               }
             }
             else { //Не явно s.start>=t.start
                 if(t.finish>=s.finish)
                 {
                     if(!one_iter.hasNext()) {
                         result.addAll(two);
                         two.clear(); //Костыль - На случай кросс
                     }
                     one.remove(s);
                     one_iter=one.listIterator();
                     continue OUTER;
                 }
                 if(t.finish<s.finish){
                     s.start=t.finish+1;
                     result.add(t);
                     two.remove(t);
                     two_iter = two.listIterator();
                 }
             }
         }
      }
        result.addAll(two);
        result.addAll(one);
        return result;
    }
```

**Вопрос:** в такой метод может поступить два массива с тысячой элементов каждый. Как его коротко и ёмко переписать средствами **stream API java 8**? И можно ли это сделать? И так, чтобы не было полного обхода сравнения каждого с каждым **(** O(n^2) - не устраивает, нужно O(n*log(n)), в крайнем случае O(n^1.1) **)**.
В более широком смысле вопрос - есть ли какой-нибудь алгоритм быстрого переписывания старого легаси кода стредствами java 8?

Comment: то что это делается с помощью команды flatmap - мне тоже понятно, не понятно как столько логики запихать в стримы.

Comment: Непонятно, нафига тут стримы.

Comment: как это нафига? Для автоматического распаралелиливания, если придут массивы по 3000 элементов каждый.

Comment: Параллелить линейный алгоритм на 3К элементов? Нафига? Тем более, он не параллелится потому что массивы могут вообще не пересекаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задачу можно решить за `O(nlogn)`. Задачу можно решить потоками. Решение сложное так как опирается на заметание.

[Кли](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Klee) предложил заметание для решения задачи названной его именем: [Klee's measure problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klee%27s_measure_problem). На русском: [поиск длины объединения отрезков на прямой](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/length_of_segments_union).

Заметание - общая технология. У вас есть упорядоченная очередь **событий**, обрабатывая события вы обновляете **состояние** (**статус**). В зависимости от изменения состояния вы печатаете (выводите) **результат**. Алгоритм потоковый: события считываются из потока и результаты выводятся в другой поток. В сложных случаях несколько заметаний могут быть объеденены в конвейер.

Ниже решаем такую задачу: нужно удалить те части зелёных отрезков, которые покрыты синими. Это не вся задача из вопроса, но самая сложная её часть. Когда это сделано останется в результат подмешать синие отрезки.

В нашей задаче событием будет конец отрезка. Событие характеризуется координатой, типом конца (начало или конец), признаком включена или нет сама точка события в отрезок (полуинтервал, интервал), цветом (зеленый или синий).

Например зелёный отрезок [0, 10] породит два зелёных события, которые можно изобразить так:

```
0         10
01234567890123
[         ]
```

Для синих отрезков автор вопроса предлагает нотацию `[5, 6]` которая сбивает с толку. Преобразуем синие отрезки: `[5, 6] -> (4, 7)` - отрезок расширен, а концы его исключены. Событиями будут точки `4` и `7`:

```
0         10
01234567890123
    (  )
```

Зелёный `[0, 10]` и синий `[5, 6]` вместе:

```
0         10
01234567890123
[   (  )  ]
```

Состояние будет состоять из двух битов: бит `g` означает "в зеленом отрезке", бит `b` - "внутри синего" (в этой фразе "в" и "внутри" - разные вещи!). Последняя строка "зелёный без синего":

```
0         10
01234567890123
[   (  )  ]
-----------   g        покрыто зелёным отрезком
     --       b        покрыто синим интервалом
-----  ----   g & ~b   зелёный, но не синий
```

Распишем события и состояния для последней картинки:

```
 x e g b g&~b комментарий
     0 0 0
 0 [ 1 0 1    переход g&~b 0->1: печатаем '0['
 4 ( 1 1 0    переход g&~b 1->0: печатаем '4]'
 7 ) 1 0 1    переход g&~b 0->1: печатаем '7['
10 ] 0 0 0    переход g&~b 1->0: печатаем '10]'
```

Итоговая распечатка. Её можно собрать попарно чтобы получить отрезки:

```
0[, 4], 7[, 10]    ->    [0, 4], [7, 10]
```

Более сложный пример. Зелёные `[0, 3], [5, 8], [10, 13], [18, 20]`. Синие `[2, 6], [9, 13], [17, 17], [18, 18]`. Отратите внимание на два синих отрезка в конце - они пересеклись:

```
0         10        20
012345678901234567890123456789
[  ] [  ] [  ]    [ ]
 (     )(     ) ( )
                 ( )
---- ---- ----    ---   g
  -----  -----   --     b
--     --          --   g & ~b
```

События и состояния:

```
 x e g b g&~b комментарий
     0 0 0
 0 [ 1 0 1    переход g&~b 0->1: печатаем '0['
 1 ( 1 1 0    переход g&~b 1->0: печатаем '1]'
 3 ] 0 1 0
 5 [ 1 1 0
 7 ) 1 0 1    переход g&~b 0->1: печатаем '7['
 8 ] 0 0 0    переход g&~b 1->0: печатаем '8]'
 8 ( 0 1 0
10 [ 1 1 0
13 ] 0 1 0
14 ) 0 0 0
16 ( 0 1 0
17 ( 0 2 0    синие могут пересекаться. b - не бит, а счётчик
18 ) 0 1 0
18 [ 1 1 0
19 ) 1 0 1    переход g&~b 0->1: печатаем '19['
20 ] 0 0 0    переход g&~b 1->0: печатаем '20]'
```

Печать целиком:

```
[0, 1], [7, 8], [19, 20]
```

Таким образом из зелёных отрезков удаляются участки выделеные синими. Полученные отрезки надо смешать с оригинальными (не раздутыми) синими, что даст ответ.

Заметание позволяет за линейное время вычислить любую булеву функцию на совокупностях отрезков (предварительная сортировка добавляет `nlogn`).

Программа:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SegmentOverlapping {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        test(
            new Segment[] { new Segment(0, 3), new Segment(5, 8), new Segment(10, 13), new Segment(18, 20) },
            new Segment[] { new Segment(2, 6), new Segment(9, 13), new Segment(17, 17), new Segment(18, 18) }
        );
        test(
            new Segment[] { new Segment(0, 10), new Segment(11, 11) },
            new Segment[] { new Segment(5, 6), new Segment(11, 11) }
        );
    }

    private static void test(Segment[] green, Segment[] blue) {
        System.out.println("-");
        printSegments("g", Stream.of(green));
        printSegments("b", Stream.of(blue));
        printSegments("r", maskGreenByBlue(green, blue));
    }

    private static void printSegments(String prefix, Stream<Segment> segments) {
        System.out.print(prefix + ":");
        segments.forEach(s -> System.out.print(" " + s));
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static Stream<Segment> maskGreenByBlue(Segment[] green, Segment[] blue) {
        Stream<Event> masked = maskGreenByBlueEvents(green, blue);

        Stream.Builder<Segment> builder = Stream.builder();

        Stream
        .concat(
            masked,
            makeStream(blue, Color.BLUE, 0)
        )
        .sorted()
        .forEach(new SegmentHandler(builder));

        return builder.build();
    }

    private static Stream<Event> maskGreenByBlueEvents(Segment[] green, Segment[] blue) {
        Stream.Builder<Event> builder = Stream.builder();

        Stream
        .concat(
            makeStream(green, Color.GREEN, 0),
            makeStream(blue, Color.BLUE, 1)
        )
        .sorted()
        .forEach(new BlueMaskHandler(builder));

        return builder.build();
    }

    private static Stream<Event> makeStream(Segment[] segments, Color color, int margin) {
        return Stream
            .of(segments)
            .map(s -> Stream.of(
                new Event(color, Edge.START , s.start  - margin,  margin),
                new Event(color, Edge.FINISH, s.finish + margin, -margin)
            ))
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
        ;
    }
}

class Segment {
    public final int start;
    public final int finish;

    public Segment(int start, int finish) {
        this.start = start;
        this.finish = finish;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + start + ", " + finish + "]";
    }
}

enum Edge { START, FINISH; }

enum Color { GREEN, BLUE; }

class Event implements Comparable<Event> {
    public final Color color;
    public final Edge edge;
    public final int x;
    public final int dx;
    public Event(Color color, Edge edge, int x, int dx) {
        this.color = color;
        this.edge = edge;
        this.x = x;
        this.dx = dx;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Event other) {
        int cX = Integer.compare(x, other.x);
        if (cX != 0) {
            return cX;
        }
        return Integer.compare(dx, other.dx);
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + color + " " + edge + " " + x;
    }
}

class BlueMaskHandler implements Consumer<Event> {
    private final Stream.Builder<Event> builder;
    private int inGreen;
    private int inBlue;

    public BlueMaskHandler(Stream.Builder<Event> builder) {
        this.builder = builder;
        inGreen = 0;
        inBlue = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Event event) {
        switch (event.color) {
        case GREEN:
            switch (event.edge) {
            case START:
                if (inGreen == 0 && inBlue == 0) {
                    builder.add(event);
                }
                ++inGreen;
                break;
            case FINISH:
                --inGreen;
                if (inGreen == 0 && inBlue == 0) {
                    builder.add(event);
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
        case BLUE:
            switch (event.edge) {
            case START:
                if (inBlue == 0 && inGreen > 0) {
                    builder.add(new Event(Color.GREEN, Edge.FINISH, event.x, 0));
                }
                ++inBlue;
                break;
            case FINISH:
                --inBlue;
                if (inBlue == 0 && inGreen > 0) {
                    builder.add(new Event(Color.GREEN, Edge.START, event.x, 0));
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

class SegmentHandler implements Consumer<Event> {
    private final Stream.Builder<Segment> builder;
    private int start;

    public SegmentHandler(Stream.Builder<Segment> builder) {
        this.builder = builder;
        start = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Event event) {
        switch (event.edge) {
        case START:
            start = event.x;
            break;
        case FINISH:
            builder.add(new Segment(start, event.x));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac SegmentOverlapping.java && java SegmentOverlapping 
> -
> g: [0, 3] [5, 8] [10, 13] [18, 20]
> b: [2, 6] [9, 13] [17, 17] [18, 18]
> r: [0, 1] [2, 6] [7, 8] [9, 13] [17, 17] [18, 18] [19, 20]
> -
> g: [0, 10] [11, 11]
> b: [5, 6] [11, 11]
> r: [0, 4] [5, 6] [7, 10] [11, 11]
> ```

Comment: Ставлю плюс, но я пока ничего не понимаю

Comment: Я привёл ссылки на оригинальное заметание. Надеюсь будет проще понять схему.

Comment: Слишком сложно, но никто не предложил за целый месяц более крутого решения.

Comment: Заметание - простая технология. Просто никто не обучает как ею пользоваться, к сожалению.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже бесперспективно переписывать любой код средствами Java 8 stream api, если важен порядок перебора элементов.
Сами потоки хорошо подходят для применения однотипной операции ко всем элементам. Там где нужно сравнивать один элемент, с другим элементом массива, [потоки не подходят](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31650397/5117196), потому как они не поддерживают операцию **next()**;  Так что по состоянию на 2021 год, наверное нужно оставлять в этом участке кода итераторы.